# dbf file operations in C# .net

Tags: c#, dbf

I need to create a dbf file which has the table structure of an existing dbf and insert data to it. Also I need to specify the NAME for it which i usually do in excel by insert->Name.
Which is the best and easy way for it. I have tried using OLEDB already. But I need suggestions for the best option.

Comment: You can use the `VFPOLEDB` provider to work with DBF's. What version of DBF are you trying to emulate? What's going to read it? I recently had to create `dBase III` compatible DBF files and managed it, but it was *pain*.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932530/how-to-create-a-dbf-file-from-scratch-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFileName, destFileName);
```

Followed by opening the new file and truncating the data leaving the table structure?