# Creating a DBF File, as part of a shape file, without a DBT file - in C#

Tags: c#, dbf, shapefile, dbase

I want to create a DBF file: it should be dBase III format.

- As part of an ESRI Shapefile
- dBase format III
- **WITHOUT** A MEMO \ DBT FILE.
- Single column multiple rows.

I've tried a lot of options the closest I got was using this: ( But it creates the annoying memo file along with it ).

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\temp;Extended Properties=dBase III";

using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
using (OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    connection.Open();

    command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Test (Id Integer, Changed Double, Name Text)";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

as was [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932530/how-to-create-a-dbf-file-from-scratch-in-c).

Comment: what's your question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't come back to see this but this is to you and others who might benefit:

I'm also working on ESRI's shapefile and found that changing that connection string to specify the Provider to VFPOLEDB solves the problem.
Try:

```
 string connectionString = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=D:\temp;Extended Properties=dBase III";
```

VFPOLEDB is Visual Fox Pro provider for Ole DB.